# Trouble with setup in Windows RT 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-rt

I'm making a program for a Windows Surface Pro with Windows RT 8.1, but when I want to run the setup in it, it doesn't work. It says that the version of windows don't allows the application I'm trying to execute, but in Setup Wizard of Visual Studio 2012 I say that my application doesn't require any specific operating system. Which can be the solution

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think the Surface Pro runs Windows RT, and you can't run Visual Studio on RT anyway AFAIW

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Visual Studio on Windows RT.

I'm quoting a Microsoft employee here :

> Only software written using the Windows Runtime (Metro style apps) can be used on Windows RT with the exception of Microsoft Office 2013 and the desktop version of Internet Explorer 10. Developers will not be able to create applications to run on Windows RT using the Win32 APIs

He answered that on a related [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a928cc7-56d9-4f61-a77f-5d2bdfc05bb8/visual-studio-2012-on-windows-rt?forum=vssetup) in MSDN